# Can women do manuals on BMX?

Tags: bmx

Ok, so I've just begun really getting focused on BMX. I know that mostly it's guys doing BMX and they inspire me to push myself to do what they do. But I just couldn't help but notice, after watching so many manual videos I can't find a single one of a girl doing a regular manual. I've been practicing myself and I've been able to find the balance point for a second or two so I know its possible... Or is it? Men are built different with longer legs and arms, and are just generally bigger. But I've seen little kids doing manuals too... So surely a women would be able to do one? How come I don't see any videos of it?! I'm gonna try to master it, maybe I'll be the first to upload a video of it... To prove that it's possible.

But just why don't I ever see females doing more manuals?

Comment: In a word, yes. I've seen a few in real life on various bikes, and videos on BMX.  I'm trying to remember the name of the all-female group that has made some nice technique videos, and I'll add an answer if I recall it.

Comment: Maybe simply because there aren't as many women interested in doing so and, therefore, there are fewer who do so & post videos online...

Comment: just a little comment: While men and women are _on average_ built differently, the variance between individual men, or women, is greater than the variance between average men and average women. So if "men" can do something that does not require men-only-bodyparts, then women can, too, although not every woman might be able to, but neither is every man.

Comment: This question sounds as if a girl can write a proper user manual for a bicycle :)

Comment: "I'm gonna try to master it, maybe I'll be the first to upload a video of it... To prove that it's possible." 100% in support of this! It's the proper response to _any_ "why don't we see people of `group X` doing `activity Y`?" If you're in `group X` and `activity Y` interests you, just go do it. You'll probably find that you'll get a _ton_ of support from those who are watching you practice, and that you'll run into one or two jerks claiming that "`group X` _can't_ do `activity Y`", but you'll find those one or two idiots complaining about _everything_.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can.

proof:
https://m.facebook.com/vinetapetersonee/videos/camera-man-dowwwn-saw-girls-doing-these-manuals-wanted-to-give-a-try-rip-thomass/244936933433080/

On a serious note, there are plenty of good training and instruction videos on the interwebz with women doing manuals on both bmx and trial.

Comment: Also https://www.facebook.com/USABMX/videos/learn-how-to-manual-with-dk-bicycles-carly-kane/525901828316205/